# get character set and collation from existing PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql

For an existing PDO connection object, is there a way to get the character set and collation from it?

Comment: $charset = $pdo->query("SELECT CHARSET('')")->fetchColumn();

Comment: Get the charset/collation from what? Table? Cells? Database? Connection object itself?

Comment: @Qirel From an existing PDO connection object itself.

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of that - you set that value yourself when creating the PDO connection? In the DSN parameter. But to answer your question, no - not that I know of.

Comment: @Qirel I don't set it myself. The Drupal framework does, somewhere. I just want to confirm that I've edited the `settings.php` file properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is No, you cannnot.